# TreeSet метод first() java

Tags: java

Подскажите как можно реализовать метод который должен возвращать самый малый элемент

```
public class TreeLinkedSet<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Iterable<T> {

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<T>() {
            private Container cursor;

            {
                if (root != null) {
                    cursor = passLeft(root);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return cursor != null;
            }

            @Override
            public T next() {
                T res = cursor.val;
                if (cursor.right != null) {
                    cursor = passLeft(cursor.right);

                } else if (cursor.right == null) {
                    cursor = passBack(cursor);
                }
                return res;
            }

        };
    }

    private class Container implements Comparable<Container> {

        private Container left;
        private Container right;
        private Container prior;
        private T val;

        public Container(T val) {
            this.val = val;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Container o) {
            return val.compareTo(o.val);
        }

    }
    private Container root;
    private int size;

    public int Size() {
        return size;
    }

    public void add(T t) {
        Container c = new Container(t);
        if (root == null) {
            root = c;
            size++;
        } else {
            choose(root, c);

        }
    }

    private void choose(Container base, Container c) {
        if (c.compareTo(base) < 0) {
            if (base.left == null) {
                base.left = c;
                c.prior = base;
                size++;
            } else {
                choose(base.left, c);
            }
        }
        if (c.compareTo(base) > 0) {
            if (base.right == null) {
                base.right = c;
                c.prior = base;
                size++;
            } else {
                choose(base.right, c);
            }
        }
    }

    private Container passLeft(Container c) {
        return c.left == null ? c : passLeft(c.left);
    }

    private Container passBack(Container c) {
        if (c.prior != null) {
            return c.prior.compareTo(c) > 0 ? c.prior : passBack(c.prior);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public T[] toArray(T[] type) {
        T[] res = (T[]) Array.newInstance(type.getClass().getComponentType(), size);
        int i = 0;
        for (T t : this) {
            res[i++] = t;
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый малый элемент в таком дереве — самый левый, т.ч. метод будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
public T first() {
    if(root==null) {
        //нужно понять что делать если коллекция пуста
        return null;
    }
    //в противном случае идем от корня налево до конца
    Container leftMost = root;
    while(leftMost.left!=null) {
         leftMost = leftMost.left;
    }
    return leftMost.val;
}
```

**Обновление:** Кстати, у Вас уже есть итератор, который умеет определять первый элемент. И даже есть метод для этого — `passLeft`, можно использовать его:

```
public T first() {
    if(root==null) {
        //нужно понять что делать если коллекция пуста
        return null;
    }
    //в противном случае идем от корня налево до конца
    return passLeft(root).val;
}
```

и, если для пустой коллекции метод действительно должен вернуть `null`, то можно сократить код:

```
public T first() {
    return root==null ? null : passLeft(root).val;
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо !!!!!

Comment: @EvgeniyRadion Пожалуйста! На будущее: старайтесь расписывать подробнее что делает код. Если сами пытались написать метод, то прикладывайте неудачную попытку. Так будет легче Вам помочь.

Comment: ок, понял, и еще раз спасибо

Comment: @EvgeniyRadion заметил, что у Вас в коде уже есть подходящий метод для поиска наиболее левого элемента. Обновил ответ.

Comment: а подскажи плз насчет метода удаления мне нужно очистить коллекцию я сделал так :            '    public void clear() {
        if (root != null) {
            root =null;
        }'

Comment: @EvgeniyRadion вроде норм